# Libreoffice Calc row column width larger then previous rows

Tags: libreoffice

How is it possible to have rows with a specific column spanning multiple columns or equivalently having a column larger then the columns in the previous rows?

To be clear in the below screenshot row 8 has the A column spanning up to the E column while columns B,C,D,E are hidden behind column A.
The previous row 7 instead had columns A,B,C,D,E all visible and with different widths to row 9.

How is it done?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge cells in different rows, that's not changing the actual column width of just certain rows but the result is the same as you can see in your screenshot.

Some columns are effectively masked from the others.